# How to configure Multi Source Inventory (MSI) in Magento 2.3

Tags: multistore, multishipping, magento2.3

I've heard that Magento Core guys have just developed Multi-Source Inventory functionality

(https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi).

So I guess it means that I can place my products in different countries and depots to be calculated by Magento.

I want to use this feature on my website, because I've been trying to do something like this for a long time.

So, does anybody know how to correctly configure this feature?
Also Share any helpful links or manuals ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have to tried this ??

Comment: @lalitmohan , I try but now unsuccessful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proceed on the wiki page of the project - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki and from the right side of the page you will find "MSI User Guide" which describes how to set up the project and use its main features.

Also, there is a big Slack channel devoted to "#MSI" in Magento Community Slack, which you can apply for following this link https://tinyurl.com/engcom-signup There are about 300 active participants there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.3 Source option present under

```
Stores -> Inventory -> Sources
```

You can add New source as follows:

[image]

Further worth reading article is:-

[The Definitive Guide to Magento MSI Multi Source Inventory](https://www.reachdigital.nl/en/blog/magento-msi-multi-source-inventory-features)

Answer (score 1):

**Multi Source Inventory (MSI) in Magento 2.3 Configure Points below here:**

1. **https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/tree/2.3-develop** here is the link from where you can download Magento 2.3
2. below is the mentioned command that you should follow to install
       php 7.2 and updating your repository is mandatory. apt-get update &&
       apt-get upgrade apt-get install python-software-properties
       add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php apt-get update apt-get install
       php7.2
3. To setup sample data the command mentioned below should be run. 
   php bin/magento sampledata:deploy It might ask you for username and
   password, that can be avail from here
   https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/ and you will be
   creating your account here that will give you private key and public
   key which can be used as a credentials. Your public key will be the
   username whereas;  private key will be your password.
4. below commands should be followed in order to install Magento 2.3
   finally.  php bin/magento setup:install –db-host=[your-database
   host(localhost)] –db-name=[your-database-name]
   –db-user=[databse-usename] –db-password=[database-password]
   –base-url=[url-of-your-magento-store]
   –backend-frontname=[url-endpoint-of-your-admin]
   –admin-firstname=[firstname-of-your-admin]
   –admin-lastname=[lastname-of-your-admin] –admin-email=[admin-email]
   –admin-user=[admin-username] –admin-password=[admin-password]

Performing all the above steps equally will help you in installing the Magento 2.3 with MSI on your server.

**For the detailed information about Magento 2.3**, MSI configuration along with its benefits you can also visit **[Magento 2 Multi Source Inventory (MSI) Features](https://i-verve.com/blog/magento-2-multi-source-inventory-features)**

Thanks